# Why doesn't django-modeltranslation add fields to the admin panel?

Tags: django, django-models, django-modeltranslation

I wanted data in my Django database to be translated to one more language in some cases, and to achieve that I decided to use the django-modeltranslation library. The setup went ok, but the translation fields were never actually added to the models.

I followed the installation steps and created a translation.py file with the following content:

```
from modeltranslation.translator import translator, TranslationOptions
from .models import *


class WorkTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('title', 'text')   # Select here the fields you want to translate  
class CategoryTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('name',)
translator.register(Work, WorkTranslationOptions)
translator.register(Category, CategoryTranslationOptions)
```

My models.py file looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
class Work(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    app_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False, default=timezone.now)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='works/', blank=False, null=False)
    text = models.TextField(blank=False)
    url = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

Running the python manage.py makemigrations command went fine and returned no exceptions, as well as the migrate command:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNpEZ.png)
But for some reason none of those fields were actually added to the models: I can't see them in the admin panel. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you using the [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) in your `admin.py` ? Anyway, it would be interesting if you could share us this file.

Answer (score 0):

You should see the fields in the database now. To see them in the Admin as well, inherit from the `TranslationAdmin` when registering your model in the admin.

https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html